# Does Dropbear know what a ~/.ssh/config file is?

Tags: ssh, linux-networking, openwrt, dropbear

I want to ssh from one host (OpenWrt running Dropbear) to another host on the same LAN that is running open-ssh server and client.

I converted the private open-ssh key of the other host to dropbear format and saved it to ~/.ssh/ncp_key_dropbear on the OpenWrt host.

Now I can ssh from OpenWrt to the other host like this:

```
# ssh -i ncp_key_dropbear root@192.168.1.124 -p 22
```

I also made a ~/.ssh/config file on the OpenWrt host like this:

```
Host ncp
        User root
        Port 22
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ncp_key_dropbear
        HostName 192.168.1.124
```

But when I try to ssh now with this command:

```
# ssh ncp
```

I get this error...

```
root@OpenWrt:~/.ssh# ssh ncp

ssh: Connection to root@ncp:22 exited: Connect failed: Error resolving 'ncp' port '22'. Name does not resolve
```

Actually I get the same error even if I change the Port to 1022 even though the sshd on the remote host is also listening on that port.

I set up a ~/.ssh/config file on the other host as above, except I use an open-ssh client on that host, and **can** ssh from it to OpenWrt like this:

```
# ssh openwrt
```

So why is my config file not working on the OpenWrt? Does Dropbear not know anything about ~/.ssh/config files? [Here is an article](https://yorkspace.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/using-public-keys-with-dropbear-ssh-client/) from 2009 that seems to suggest that but surely things have changed?

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: Dropbear is not OpenSSH. And nothing in that tutorial you linked to says anything about a config file.

Comment: Is that another one of those snarky responses I always get on serverfault? Yes I realize dropbear is not openssh. I provided that old link because it suggests that Dropbear may not know anything about a config file as a way to supply ssh client connection parameters. If you can help clarify this matter for me I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, neither the dropbear server nor client read a config file. If they did, it would be documented in their man pages. But a quick look at both of them shows nothing.

Comment: That was a good idea to check the man page! If you'd like to make an official answer I will accept it. Either way, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got [confirmation](https://lists.ucc.gu.uwa.edu.au/pipermail/dropbear/2021q1/002281.html) from the author of Dropbear that it does not currently support a configuration file such as ~/.ssh/config.